# Here's a photo from the party or here's a photo of the party

Tags: meaning

Is it grammatically correct to say, here's a photo from the party, or should it always be a photo of the party?

Thank you for any replies.

Comment: Which do you think is correct and why?

Comment: Please use apostrophes - `'` rather than backticks - `\``

Comment: They are both grammatical. Which you want to use depends on what you want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A photo from the party denotes a photograph of an event or location taken within the party (say, a photo of two people talking or a photo of gifts). A photo of the party has the connotation of containing a more complete picture of the party, e.g. a group photo of all of the guests.

Comment: Thank you. This is a useful explanation which I can use in the classroom.

Comment: @ThreeLions In that case do please give friend Jawi a vote, and possibly a tick!